# What is the equivalent of Spring-JDBC in CDI?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, cdi

Considering replacing Spring with CDI in new project, I've encountered a <strike>problem</strike>challenge:

We do a plenty of things with SQL queries (for which JPA isn't reasonable): invoking stored procedures, reporting, specialized queries with complicated syntax.

There's a plenty of trivial examples for CDI database access in Internet, and for trivial examples JPA is sufficient. But how do you work with SQL in JPA?

I'm looking for something like Spring-JDBC, with simplified interface for running SQL queries through JDBC and container managing transactions (through annotations), but I havent't found anything yet.

How do one work with SQL queries in CDI? Is it possible with CDI core or extensions?

Comment: What's the problem with JPA Native Queries? It's here to handle full SQL queries (stored procedure and so on) and keep some JPA benefits like second level cache.

Comment: @AntoineSabot-Durand can you use any tables in JPA Native Queries without mapping them into entities? Can you disable cache (both first and second level) completely for reporting queries? If yes, it would be my choice. But I know JPA only from Hibernate, where those things are not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything in the Spec about doing this. You'd have to create your own library, create the transaction layer (or use JTA 1.2 from Java EE 7, or Apache Deltaspike) and build it all up that way. I did mention [DeltaSpike](http://deltaspike.org), which in the (hopefully) soon to be released version 0.5 will have some of these query and other DB specific features.

Comment: DeltaSpike has a Data module that does a lot of this.

Comment: @JohnAment Right, though we're still going through some bugs it looks like, and I'm pretty sure it's based around JPA. If the OP is using things like stored procs and other DB specific bits they're probably best to stick to JBDC.

Answer (score 1):

CDI stands for Contexts/Dependency Injection (if I'm not mistaken). By itself it has nothing to do with SQL. Using CDI with JPA allows you to work with the database, but even in this case JPA does all the work. CDI has very little to do with it.

If you want to work with native queries and JPA's `nativeQuery` isn't enough, you'll have to either add the Spring-JDBC dependency to your project, or since you're moving away from Spring, another smaller library that would give you things similar to `JdbcTemplate` and such.

So to sum it up, CDI has no equivalent of Spring-JDBC, just as Spring doesn't have an equivalent of Swing GUI.

Comment: Hmm well, to use Swing GUI in Spring I don't have to include any library :D

Comment: Well no, but it's the same principle ;)